# Passing Chinese (string variable) into a query string fails to work

Tags: c#, webforms

I tried the following to compose a query string for my search:

```
String QueryString = 
"SELECT Grade_8_Exam_Date,Grade_8_Exam_Place,Grade_8_Result,Grade_8_Remark 
FROM dbo.tblMemberInfo 
WHERE Chinese_Name =" + DropDownList2.SelectedValue;
```

where the `DropDownList2.SelectedValue` is a string of Chinese characters.

Then the above fails as the value of `DropDownList2.SelectedValue` been taken as another column head. However, if I do the following:

```
String QueryString = 
"SELECT Grade_8_Exam_Date,Grade_8_Exam_Place,Grade_8_Result,Grade_8_Remark 
FROM dbo.tblMemberInfo 
WHERE Chinese_Name ='陳大文'"
```

then everything is working fine. Even though the `DropDownList2.SelectedValue` actually returns 陳大文 but when it is concatenated with the other string, it will become:

```
String QueryString = 
"SELECT Grade_8_Exam_Date,Grade_8_Exam_Place,Grade_8_Result,Grade_8_Remark 
FROM dbo.tblMemberInfo 
WHERE Chinese_Name =陳大文"
```

which fails to work.

How can this be solved?

Comment: Do not inject values into the query, use parameters. Then this issue (and more) will go away

Comment: please use ***parameterised queries*** - building SQL queries by concatenation etc. is a recipe for disaster. not only is it a source for many hard to debug syntax errors, it's also a wide, open gate for ***[SQL Injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/)***. it will also very likely fix your problem without you having to worry about it at all. (and no: there is _no_ reason not to use parameterised queries when you can use them)

Comment: If you used a parameterized query passing an `NVarChar` parameter you wouldn't have had this issue

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
String QueryString = 
"SELECT Grade_8_Exam_Date,Grade_8_Exam_Place,Grade_8_Result,Grade_8_Remark 
FROM dbo.tblMemberInfo 
WHERE Chinese_Name = ‘" + DropDownList2.SelectedValue + “‘“;
```

This makes sure the string is enclosed within ‘ and ‘.

But also take a look at the comments. In productioncode you should not concatenate SQL queries like this!

Comment: Yes, I used your code and get the problem resolved. By the way, I am fresh in C# and SQL, any chance of showing me how to do parameterised queries please ?

Comment: I tried to do this:<br/>String QureyString = "SELECT Center,Chinese_Name,Gender,JOIN_DATE FROM dbo.tblMemberInfo WHERE Chinese_Name =@Chinese_Name";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(QureyString, conn);
            SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[1];
            param[0] = new SqlParameter("@Chinese_Name", DropDownList2.SelectedValue);
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();<br/> and got the following error prompt:<br/>: 'Must declare the scalar variable "@Chinese_Name".'

Comment: Problem solved :
           String QureyString = "SELECT Center,Name_ID,Gender,JOIN_DATE FROM dbo.tblMemberInfo WHERE Chinese_Name =@Chinese_Name";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(QureyString, conn);
            SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@Chinese_Name";
            param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
            param.Value = DropDownList2.SelectedValue;
            command.Parameters.Add(param);

Many thanks for you guru's advises......